# Find a unitary matrix given its action on a class of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quantum-computation

Im studying quantum computation and have encountered an interesting problem.

I need to find an unitary matrix $U$, such that

$$U\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1\\ \vdots \\ -1 \\ \vdots \\ 1\end{bmatrix} = \frac1k\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0\\ \vdots \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

where the vector is $n\times1$ and $k$ is a constant (as necessary). Essentially, every $1$ element goes to $0$, and $-1$ goes to $1$. The $-1$ element can be present anywhere in any row the column vector, and the corresponding row in the image vector should have $1$ at that place and $0$ everywhere else.

Can we solve for $U$? If yes,how? (It need not be unique)

Comment: A unitary matrix preserves the length of a vector, so you must rescale one of your vectors if you want to find a unitary matrix transforming one to the other.

Comment: If you subtract your vector from a vector of all ones and then divide by 2 you have your desired result.

Comment: @uniquesolution thanks, I've edited to reflect that point.

Comment: @N74 Yes, but how would you represent that as a matrix or operator? I'm not sure.

Comment: Are you looking for a *single* matrix that works for all $n\times1$ vectors of this form or a specific matrix for each such vector?

Comment: Responding to ambiguity in your question, please clarify the following: Are you looking for a matrix that will satisfy these requirements simultaneously for $n$ vectors, where the $-1$ moves from place to place, in which case there is obviously no such matrix - or are you looking for a matrix that transposes one specific vector of this sort to the other?

Answer (score -1):

The constraints on $U$ can be collected into the single equation $$U(\mathbb 1_n-2I_n)=\frac1kI_n$$ where $\mathbb 1_n$ is an $n\times n$ matrix of all ones. This has the unique solution $$U=\frac1k(\mathbb 1_n-2I_n)^{-1}=\frac1{2k}\left(\frac1{n-2}\mathbb1_n-I_n\right)$$ for $n\gt2$. This $U$ is real and symmetric, so $UU^*=U^2$, which is diagonal only for $n=4$, so it doesn’t seem possible in general to construct a unitary matrix that will perform this mapping.

Comment: I believe the OP is asking for a unitary matrix transforming the left vector (all coordinates are $+1$ except one which is $-1$) to a multiple of a unit-vector. Surely such a unitary matrix exists, does it not?

Comment: @uniquesolution No, the OP asks for a matrix that transforms *every* vector of this form into the corresponding multiple of a standard basis vector. I.e., a matrix that “picks out” the $-1$.

Comment: well, I did not understand it like that. I think you are wrong.

Comment: @uniquesolution ”The $-1$ element can be present *anywhere*...” Why don’t you ask for a clarification instead of being so quick to downvote? I notice that you also haven’t offered any answer based on your understanding of the question.

Comment: Yes, the element $1$ can be present anywhere, and whenever you fixed its place, you need to find a unitary matrix as asked. Perhaps a clarification would be helpful, but I find it unthinkable that any source for quantum computation will ask a question whose answer is "there is no such matrix". Obviously they need to shift around special vectors, not to state obvious impossibilities. When I will have an answer based on my understanding that I like, I will be sure to let you know.

Comment: @uniquesolution If you’re so confident in your interpretation, post an answer or ask the OP to clarify. There’s no point in arguing this with you any further until you’ve done either and gotten a response.

Comment: @ I just did. I asked for a clarification. Who knows, maybe you are right.

Comment: @uniquesolution, I saw that possibility, but I thought that the problem has too the possibility to be one posed, not by the source directly, but by the OP as generalization or curiosity or something. Clarification helps, of course.

Answer (score -1):

The matrix cannot be unitary

$$k\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1\\ \vdots \\ -1 \\ \vdots \\ 1\end{bmatrix} = U^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0\\ \vdots \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

$$U^{-1}=k\begin{bmatrix}
-1&1&\cdots&1\\
 1&-1&\cdots&1\\
 \cdots\\
 1&1&\cdots&-1
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$U=\dfrac{1}{k}\dfrac{1}{2n-4}\begin{bmatrix}
-(n-3)&1&\cdots&1\\
 1&-(n-3)&\cdots&1\\
 \cdots\\
 1&1&\cdots&-(n-3)
\end{bmatrix}$$

For an unitary real matrix $V^{-1}=V^T$, but clearly $U^{-1}\neq U^T$. No solution for the given conditions.

Comment: I believe the OP is asking for a unitary matrix transforming the left vector (all coordinates are $+1$ except one which is $-1$) to a multiple of a unit-vector. Surely such a unitary matrix exists, does it not?

Comment: @uniquesolution A matrix $U$ defined by the action of every vector of that form is unique and at least for $n\gt3$ and it is not unitary.

Comment: Budria - I think you misunderstood the question.